# Windows Command Line To View Installed Software Hotfixes/Patches

Tags: windows, command, wmic, hotfix, installed-applications

On Windows, navigating into the **Control Panel > Programs and Features > View installed updates** page, I can see all of the software hotfixes applied including the Windows updates.

I would like to view this information using a command. Using the following command, I can view all of the Windows updates applied:

```
wmic qfe list full
```

The only problem is, the command above does not list software appliance patches applied to the machine. For example, on the **view installed updates** page, I can see a patch applied for SolarWinds and I cannot see the same information in the command line.

Comment: that'd be way too broad - you have to see how they install it - you might be able to query all installed software and check its version

Comment: You can take a look at this with Powershell : [Getting List of Installed Applications that Matches Add/Remove Programs List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63529209/getting-list-of-installed-applications-that-matches-add-remove-programs-list?answertab=active#tab-top)

Answer (score 0):

Refer to [Skipping last empty line of WMIC command output in batch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37706454/skipping-last-empty-line-of-wmic-command-output-in-batch?answertab=active#tab-top)

```bat
@echo off
Title wmic to get HotfixID
Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
echo "patches" : {
set "patches=wmic qfe get HotfixID"
for /f "skip=1" %%i in ('%patches%') do for /f "delims=" %%j in ("%%i") do (
    set /a count=count+1
    echo "!count!" : "%%j",
)
echo }
```

---

With Powershell 7.1  and refer to [Get-Package](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/packagemanagement/get-package?view=powershell-7.1) , You can give a try with Powershell :

```
Get-Package -AllVersions
```

---

[Getting List of Installed Applications that Matches Add/Remove Programs List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63529209/getting-list-of-installed-applications-that-matches-add-remove-programs-list?answertab=active#tab-top)

---

Refer to [group all installed software in one cell by PowerShell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63868213/group-all-installed-software-in-one-cell-by-powershell?answertab=active#tab-top)

```
(Get-Package | Where-Object {$_.ProviderName -in @('Programs','msi','Chocolatey')} | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name)
```