# How to list every program installed on my computer on cmd?

Tags: list, powershell, cmd, wmic

I have tried

```
Get-ItemProperty HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall | Select-Object DisplayName, DisplayVersion, Publisher, InstallDate
```

and

```
wmic product get name,version
```

None of them shows ALL the programs installed on this computer.

Comment: Add the tag Powershell and you can take a look at this : [Getting List of Installed Applications that Matches Add/Remove Programs List](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63534382/3080770)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a Powershell script : ***List_Installed_Applications.ps1***

```
$outputFile = "$env:APPDATA\Installed_Applications.txt"
$OS_Architecture = $env:PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE
if($OS_Architecture -eq 'x86') 
{
    #write-host '32-bit'
    $key = "HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\*"
}
else
{
    #write-host '64-bit'
    $key = "HKLM:\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\*"
}

Get-ItemProperty $Key |
        Select-Object DisplayName, DisplayVersion, Publisher, InstallDate |
            Format-Table –AutoSize |
                Out-File $outputFile -Encoding UTF8 -Force
                    

#Write-Host '-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------'
get-package | Format-Table -AutoSize | Out-File -Append $outputFile -Encoding UTF8 -Force #| Out-String -Width 200
Start-Process $outputFile
```

---

Here is another code but in Vbscript : ***List_Installed_Applications.vbs***

```
Title = "List All Installed Software"
Call ForceCScriptExecution(Title)
Const HKLM = &H80000002 'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE
strComputer = "."
strKey = "SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\"
strEntry1a = "DisplayName"
strEntry1b = "QuietDisplayName"
strEntry2 = "InstallDate"
strEntry3 = "VersionMajor"
strEntry4 = "VersionMinor"
strEntry5 = "EstimatedSize"

Set objReg = GetObject("winmgmts://" & strComputer & "/root/default:StdRegProv")
objReg.EnumKey HKLM, strKey, arrSubkeys

Info = Info & "Installed Applications" & VbCrLf

For Each strSubkey In arrSubkeys
    intRet1 = objReg.GetStringValue(HKLM, strKey & strSubkey,strEntry1a, strValue1)
    
    If intRet1 <> 0 Then
        objReg.GetStringValue HKLM, strKey & strSubkey,strEntry1b,strValue1
    End If
    
    If strValue1 <> "" Then
        Info = Info & VbCrLf & "Display Name : " & strValue1
    End If
    
    objReg.GetStringValue HKLM, strKey & strSubkey,strEntry2, strValue2
    
    If strValue2 <> "" Then
        Info = Info & " | Install Date : " & strValue2
    End If
    
    objReg.GetDWORDValue HKLM, strKey & strSubkey,strEntry3, intValue3
    objReg.GetDWORDValue HKLM, strKey & strSubkey,strEntry4, intValue4
    
    If intValue3 <> "" Then
        Info = Info & " | Version: " & intValue3 & "." & intValue4
    End If
    
    objReg.GetDWORDValue HKLM, strKey & strSubkey,strEntry5, intValue5
    If intValue5 <> "" Then
        Info = Info & " | Size : " & Round(intValue5/1024, 3) & " MB"
    End If
Next
wscript.echo Info
wscript.sleep 5000
MsgBox "OK ALL is Done !",vbInformation,Title
'---------------------------------------------------------------
Sub ForceCScriptExecution(Title)
    Dim Arg, Str, cmd
    cmd = "CMD /C Title "& Title &" & "
    If Not LCase( Right( WScript.FullName, 12 ) ) = "\cscript.exe" Then
        For Each Arg In WScript.Arguments
            If InStr( Arg, " " ) Then Arg = """" & Arg & """"
            Str = Str & " " & Arg
        Next
        CreateObject( "WScript.Shell" ).Run _
           cmd & "cscript //nologo """ & _
            WScript.ScriptFullName & _
            """ " & Str
        WScript.Quit
    End If
End Sub
'---------------------------------------------------------------
```